# What kind of object is this in Java script? and how to add this kind of elements in to this object?

Tags: javascript, object, element

```
var POWER = {
    '1ST_TERMINAL': { 'Lower': 1000, 'Upper': 2100 },
    '2ND_TERMINAL': { 'Lower': -100, 'Upper': -200 },
    '3RD_TERMINAL': { 'Lower': -900, 'Upper': -2700 },
    '4TH_TERMINAL': { 'Lower': 400, 'Upper': 900},
    '5TH_TERMINAL': { 'Lower': -900, 'Upper': 100 },
    '6TH_TERMINAL': { 'Lower': -810, 'Upper': 1150 }    
};
```

I know how to access the elements in this object POWER

For Example if I want to access 1ST_TERMINAL Lower value, I would do this.

```
var value = POWER['1ST_TERMINAL'].Lower;
```

So value will have "1000" now, I think 1ST_TERMINAL is some kind of key to POWER object right?? I am not sure what it is called as..

How to add same kind of element for example 7TH_TERMINAL in to POWER??

Comment: '1ST_TERMINAL' is a key/property of the object.

Answer (score 0):

simple put, use an equal sign

```
// create the object first
// 7TH_TERMINAL is a method of the object POWER
POWER['7TH_TERMINAL'] = {},
// add properties
// lower is a property which equals 1000 of the method 7TH_TERMINAL

POWER['7TH_TERMINAL'].Lower = 1000;
POWER['7TH_TERMINAL'].Upper = -1000;
```

Comment: Thank you for responding.Do you know what kind of object is this??? I mean any name for these kind of objects?? Is there any other easy way to add elements in to this object.

Comment: @JayHarris—there is no such thing as a "JSON object". It's an *ObjectLiteral*, which is described in the [Primary Expressions](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1) part of ES5. JSON is text and uses ObjectLiterals as its notation (which is why it's called JavaScript Object Notation).

Answer (score 0):

It is <strike>JSON (JavaScript object notation) object</strike> an [*ObjectLiteral*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1).

To create another node you can do something like this

```
var node = {'7TH_TERMINAL': {'Lower': 0, 'Upper': 100}};
POWER.push(node);
```

Comment: What is 7TH_TERMINAL called as in terms of POWER object?? Is it called as "KEY" to POWER object or is there any other name??

Comment: @PrudhviNath—it is a *property name*, also called a *key*

Answer (score 0):

`Power` is <strike>a JSON object</strike> an [ObjectLiteral](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1).

To create the new property/key '7TH_TERMINAL' you can do the following:

```
Power['7TH_TERMINAL'] = {}; //Create the property/key
Power['7TH_TERMINAL'].Upper = 1500;
Power['7TH_TERMINAL'].Lower = 600;
```

Alternatively, you can create the '7TH_TERMINAL' with:

```
Power['7TH_TERMINAL'] = {Upper: 1500, Lower: 600}; //Create the property/key and assign values
```